# How to make Ajax work with form_tag in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I tried multiple Youtube tutorials and StackOverflow questions but my Ajax still doesn't work with form_tag. How can I make it work?

Basically I want the td of the course to be removed after selecting the checkbox and clicking the submit button.

Here is the code:

**_courses.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_tag delete_drafts_path, remote: true do %>

  <%= submit_tag 'Update', class: 'course-container-new-row-button' %>

  <% @courses_drafts.each do |course| %>
   <tr>
    <td">
     <div class="check-button">
      <label>
       <%= check_box_tag "approved_ids[]", course.id, nil %>
        <span>
         <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></I>
        </span>
       </label>
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**courses.js.erb:**

```
$('.course-container-new-row-button').bind("ajax:success", function() {
    $(this).closest('td').fadeOut();
})
```

**courses_controller.rb:**

```
def courses 
  @courses_pending = Course.where(activity: 2).page(params[:page]).order('day ASC')

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

**Routes:**

```
  post :delete_drafts, to: "courses#courses", as: :delete_drafts
```

Comment: Can you please share log when you click on submit button?

Answer (score 0):

To make remote forms work you have to include `rails-ujs` (or `jquery-ujs` for Rails < 5.1) in your `application.js`, check if it has this line:

```js
//= require rails-ujs
```

Comment: I do have that line //= require rails-ujs and remote: true works fine.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "ajax doesn't work"? Do you see XHR request in the browser console when you submit the form?